# How can I sort a vector based on the indices contained in a different vector?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a vector that I would like to sort based on the indices contained in another vector. For instance, if I have these vectors:

```
 x <- c(0.4, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2) #<--values to be sorted
 y <- c(3,1,4,2)# <--indices to base the sorting
```

Vector y will always have distinct values from 1 to the length of x (and therefore, both vectors will always have the same number of elements)

The expected vector would be:

```
 0.8,0.2,0.4,0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use `order`

```
x[order(y)]
## [1] 0.8 0.2 0.4 0.1
```

Comment: Great! Very elegant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try `rev(x[y])` to get your expected output.

Comment: I can't see how rev can be used in my case. But thanks anyway!